# angularjs django integration

Tags: angularjs, django

I can load the page with items if I include the angularjs declaration inside script tag in index.html. Otherwise, not working.

app/templates/app/index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "javascript/app.js"%}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "components/angular/angular.min.js"%}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "components/angular-route/angular-route.js"%}"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="store">
      <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        {% verbatim %}
        <div class="panel" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <p>{{ item.id }}</p>
        </div>
      {% endverbatim %}
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

app/static/javascript/app.js

```
angular.module('store', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('ItemController', function($scope, $http) {
         $http.get('/api/items').success(function(data){
           $scope.items = data;
         });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and then get a good answer.

Comment: "Not working" how?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the angular plugin on chrome, when I load the page, it shows me this error. "Module was created but never loaded". After playing for a while, I figure it is because I load my app.js before I load angular.js.